# How did SSMS know the difference between SQL Server in Docker and host SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms

I'm running Docker on my Windows 11 host machine.

I created a container with following:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I have SSMS and SQL Server 2022 installed on host machine. Wouldn't this be considered localhost port 1433? Yet I can access both Docker version and host version of SQL Server.

Can someone help me understand how I am able to access both instances when I'm thinking both should be considered localhost 1433?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What port is the default instance actually running on, and do you have the SQL Server Browser running? It's impossible to be able to connect to both on port 1433 if are on the same port on the host.

Comment: It's very likely that your SQL Server 2022 uses https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/shared-memory-properties instead. Try stopping the container and check what port are being used, also try specifically enabling TCP/IP protocol for 2022 and then running the container again.

Answer (score 1):

> how I am able to access both instances when I'm thinking both should be considered localhost 1433?

Developer Edition and Express Edition on Windows have TCP/IP turned off by default, so wouldn't be listening on port 1433.

In any case Configuration Manager and the SQL Server ERRORLOG will both tell you what network protocols and ports an instance is listening on.  From the screenshots you posted you can see that only one of the isntances is listening on port 1433.